# Sessions controlled manually

Tags: php

I am trying to create a unique session per user to store some data. The user's in this case are http requests coming from an IOS app so there is no browser here its just using HTTP as a convenience. Hence there is not automagic session suppport. Each client is uniquely identified so I wanted to use that name as their session key. The goal is to count how many times each client has sent a message to us.

```
session_name($sname."S");
session_start();

//If we have a stored server message index in the session we will use that instead of what
//we pulled from that database
if(isset($_SESSION['count']))
{
    $serverMessageIndex = $_SESSION['count'];
}
else
{
    $serverMessageIndex = $msgIndex - 1;
}

//Later

$_SESSION['count'] = $serverMessageIndex + 1;
```

The idea here is that no message from the client can be sent twice with the same number because the counter keeps going up. However when I tried this out by sending a number of requests each with a higher number then the last, a printout of $serverMessageIndex showed 2,2,7,2,2,7 where as I would have expected 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Details on how the client sends this:
A ios app is generating a url request with only 1 paramater. This is a json variable encrypted and base64 encoded. The php is pulling from that json the variable $sname above. This variable is going to be available in every request that comes from the client.

Comment: what are you trying to count exactly? this is not going to count the number of sessions because you only have access to one session here

Comment: Answer put into post (Right above the code)

Answer (score 0):

For sessions to work, the session id has to 'come back' to the server. Either through cookies OR as part of URL. Since there is no browser, there is no cookie. So then you should use URL based session ids. Read through this http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Though what you attempted should work as well. Remember to shut off auto session start in php.ini

Comment: the variable $sname is being pulled from the URL higher up in the code. Is there something I have to do other then just have that and use it? session auto start is off.

Comment: I have update the post with more details about how this works

Comment: I do not know why named session is not working; if you want to try the alternative proposed, please read through the link. You have to use specific things in the URL to pass along session ids.

Comment: I am unable to use a specific syntax as all my URL params come inside one encrypted json paylod